# cell value in gridview is not getting in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

im not getting the valu of specic row in row data bound event , value coming null;

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Today's pos
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Label ID="lbl_TodayPos" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CurrentPosition") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

aspx.cs code
 protected void GrdKeyWord_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
      string value = GrdKeyWord.Rows[rowindex].Cells[5].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value you are looking for is stored in a label control not in a table cell. Therefore, you need to use `FindControl` on that row to access the `lbl_TodayPos`:

```
Label myLabel = (Label)GrdKeyWord.Rows[rowindex].FindControl("lbl_TodayPos");
string value = myLabel.Text;
```

If you **autogenerate** the columns in the gridview, or if you used 'BoundField' (instead of `TemplateField`) you could use `.Cells[]`. Because, in this case, you would have gridview rendered as pure html table with table cells.